# Sending an array over UDP connection

Tags: python, arrays, udp

I want to send an array using a UDP connection. When I use the sendto function, it complains that it must be a string. Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must serialize your data (in this case is an array) before sending it. Then in receiver, you will deserialize to get the original data.

You can do it in `Python`, using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) module:

```
import cPickle as p

# Sender
data_str = p.dumps(array)
sock.sendto(data_str, addr)

# Receiver
data,addr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
data_origin = p.loads(data)
```